# Disable WordPress TwentyEleven's responsive structure

Tags: html, wordpress, css, responsive-design

I've created a child theme of twentyeleven and have copied header.php and removed the following code from the file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Also, I've removed all styles (in style.css of twentyeleven) starting from:

```
/* =Responsive Structure
----------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
```

all the way down to just before:

```
/* =Print
----------------------------------------------- */
```

But still the page width is responsive on the site [here](http://fusion.fusionconstruction.co.uk/) and all elements overlay each other when you resize the browser window.

I don't need the page to resize or any element to move when I resize the window or use a mobile/tablet browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
#page {
margin: 2em auto;
max-width: 1000px;
}
```

set in your style.css.  Change this to

```
#page {
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

to set an explicit width and stop the page from resizing.

Comment: That did it just fine. Thanks for your help @apkostka. :)